# Can a variable be statistically insignificant but its components be significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, standardization

There is a paper ([here](http://finpko.faculty.ku.edu/myssi/FIN938/Sias.Herding.2002.pdf)) which shows that the beta coefficient of a standardised variable (see equation 3 in the paper), which represents the correlation between the standardised variables, can be split into two additive components (see equation 4).

My question is, can the beta coefficient from the regression be statistically insignificant, but one or both of the components be significant?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my experience it can but it is rare. I have had a variable that was comprised of three components. I have seen one and two of the components come out significant but the overall not have a significant beta coefficient.